# Updating receive and send message size for grpc in golang

Tags: go, grpc

I have grpc server written in Go and I am trying to update receive and send message size to 20MB instead of the default 4MB with the following code

```
var s *grpc.Server
s = grpc.NewServer(grpc.MaxRecvMsgSize(1024*1024*20), grpc.MaxSendMsgSize(1024*1024*20))

pb.RegisterProductServer(s,mysrv)
```

But the above doesn't seem to be working as I still get an error when I tried to call from a client `received message larger than max (5807570 vs. 4194304)"`
Not sure whats overriding the size

Comment: Hey @Dolt, curious if you later find any solution that can make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't had the chance to test this yet but have you tried adding the same options from the client stub? The same options can be attached as dial options:

```
maxMsgSize := 1024*1024*20
conn, err := grpc.Dial(address, grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions(grpc.MaxRecvMsgSize(maxMsgSize), grpc.MaxSendMsgSize(maxMsgSize)))
if err != nil {
    // ...
}
defer conn.close()
client := pb.NewProductClient(conn)
// ...
```

I don't know anything about your use case but if your response data can be delivered piece wise then the [streaming APIs](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts.html#server-streaming-rpc) might be useful.

Comment: Thank you! Can we not control this at the server level instead of client

Comment: From the documentation it would appear you can't (if your method above doesn't do the trick I don't think anything else will). Maybe file a feature request in the GitHub repo? https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues

Comment: Hey @kingkupps, Is there any other way to do this without using `grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions`? Since, this datatype was defined only in same later version of grpc. And, I have some restrictions to update my grpc version.